# Filter the records by a certain value in kafka connect

Tags: json, sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have been trying to find a way to include a filter that discards the records with a particular value, in the debezium source sql connector. Lets say, I have the JSON: {"id":0, "name":"muj"} and I want to discard all the records that have the field "name" value as "muj". Is there a way to do that without having to use confluent platform?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the *filter* function of Kafka Connect transformations (the one from Confluent). The filter function allows to include or exclude records that match the predicate based on record values. Please, see [transforms/filter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html#confluent-filter) documentation and examples.

Comment: That requires the confluent hub client, and confluent is not required here

Comment: @MujtabaFaizi It does not. It is just a jar file which you can download from https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/connect-transforms and place in the connectors directory.

Comment: @Muj To clarify, all that client does is provide a way to download and extract the plugins from Confluent's site and setup your own Kafka Connect installation programmatically. It doesn't require any part of Confluent Platform

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do that without having to use confluent platform

Confluent is not a special version of Kafka. All their tools will work with your own Kafka installation.

You can use ksql or Kafka Streams individually, but IMO, Debezium shouldn't be filtering anything, it's meant to read raw CDC events. Any such filtering should be done downstream in your processing logic